# Gaussian expectation over $f(x)^n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: integration, statistics, asymptotics

I am interested in the asymptotics as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)^n e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}} dx$$

Is there a general way to determine the asymptotics of this integral based on the properties of $f$?

Comment: Look up Laplace’s Method.

Comment: If you can find $$F(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{f(x)z-x^2}\,dx$$ then your value is $F^{(n)}(0).$

Comment: If $f>0$ and has a single maximum at $x=x_0$ (+ some mild conditions) then
$$
\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {(f(x))^{n} e^{ - x^2 /2} dx}  \sim (f(x_0 ))^{n+1} e^{ - x_0^2 /2} \sqrt {\frac{{2\pi }}{{n\left| {f''(x_0 )f(x_0 ) - (f'(x_0 ))^2 } \right|}}} 
$$ by the method of Laplace.